# Adding moving spark effect to element border

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a border. The div contains a multiselect element (via jquery). This multiselect button is a filter of sorts. When the filter is on, I want the animation style to change so the user has a constant reminder that the filter is on. I saw this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qYpck/

```
.link-list a:hover>span, .link-list a:focus>span {
background-position: -100% 0;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s;
-o-transition: background 0.4s;
transition: background 0.4s;
}
```

in which one hovers over the link and the moving spark effect zooms across the href link space. It looks nice, and I was wondering if it could be utilized for what I'm talking about. Essentially, I am sure I could figure out the timing and such for an animation. So working on it just working with hover would be fine. But when one hovers over an element, in this case the multiselect button, I would want that same effect to start at a corner of the border (preferably top left) and go to the right corner, down to the bottom right corner, left to the bottom left corner, and back up to the top left corner. And it would continue to do this. Is it possible to have this effect work on the border of an element?

Comment: Well first of all, partial borders are not possible. You'll have to use a nested element with absolute in relative positioning.

Comment: Are you thinking of [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/dotsznn0/) (Use a webkit browser. I only made the animations for webkit).

Comment: Yes. That is what I want. But does it have to be an a element?

Comment: No. It can be anything. I just used a because the sample you provided used a. It can be any element as long as it is block or inline-block.